slicing the last letter of a string in python while having both a start and stop-value?
Is it possible to slice the last letter of a string in python while still having stop-value? I would like to create a loop to slice all the letters of a string individually from the back to the front, something like this:
str = "help"

for i in range(len(str)):
    letter = str[-(i+1):-i]
    print(letter, end=", ")

This would in an ideal world print "p, l, e, h, " but this approach does not work since it doesn't print the 'p'. I found that I could slice the 'p' by skipping the stop-value (letter = str[-1:]) but this would not be possible within the loop. I would then need to put the first slicing (of the p) outside of the loop which would be really annoying. Another solution could be to add a space in the string at the end but is there a better, "real", solution to this problem which allows me to keep both the loop and the string unaffected?
EDIT:
I think I might have been a bit unclear in the question, so I just want to clarify that: I am not trying to just reverse the string, but rather extract the letters one by one from the back, do some things with them inside the loop before going back and doing the same thing with the next letter. The print thing is only for demonstrative purposes in the question :)
Like @Barmar and @interjay mentioned in their comments, I could just use index instead of slicing to solve my problem. Turns out, I'm just stupid and didn't think of that at all. But thanks to everyone else who contributed! Your answers might come in handy in the future!

Are you wanting to print the letters in reverse order?

Don't use str for a variable name.  That's the name of the builtin string class.  Redefining it will only lead to trouble.  Use something like s instead.

for letter in str[::-1]: avoids the problem completely.

The problem is that -i is 0 on the first iteration. Why are you using a slice instead of an index if you only want one character?

"but this would not be possible within the loop." sure it would

You can just write str[-(i+1)] if all you need is a single letter, there's no need for slicing.

first of all, as Tom Karzes mentioned, don't name a string str.
the most efficient way to solve your problem would be this:
string = "help"
for c in reversed(string):
    print(c, end=', ')


You might also consider
>>> print((', ').join(reversed("help")))
p, l, e, h


A simple way would be reversing the string and printing it using slice notation
your_string = "help"
your_string = your_string[::-1]

print((', ').join(your_string))

A one liner would be
print((', ').join(your_string[::-1]))

[::-1] notation explained :-
The Slice notation in python has the following syntax -
[<start>:<stop>:<step>]

So, when you use your_string[::-1], it basically starts from the end towards the first taking each element
